# Using too many "while True:" loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

My code will be below. I am practicing Python and wanted to make a simple restaurant tip calculator. It works fine, but I feel like I have relied too heavily on while loops. For each input prompt, I wanted to have the script check for if the input was a int/float and if not it would continue the loops until a proper input was given.

Does anyone have advice on if this is a good way to go about this sort of "check"?

ALSO:

Before I put the "#DETERMINING TIP PERCENTAGE BASED ON QUALITY" and following sections in their own while loop (they were originally by themselves at the end of the code NOT in a loop), I could not get the script to move on to those sections after the "How was the quality of your service?" section. The script kept looping ONLY that section. Any idea why? It seems to be formatted exactly like the other 2 while loops before it.

Thank you all. Here's my code:

```
while True :
    try :
        total = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))
        if total < 1 :
            print('Please enter a value greater than 0. ')
            continue
    except :
        print('Please enter a numerical value. ')
        continue

    while True :
        try :
            guests = int(input('How many guests? '))
            if guests < 1 :
                print('Please enter a value greater than 0. ')
                continue
        except :
            print('Please enter a numerical value. ')
            continue

        while True :
            try :
                quality = int(input('How was the quality of your service? 1 - 3: '))
                if quality > 3 or quality < 1 :
                    print('Please enter a value between 1 and 3. ')
                    continue
            except :
                print('Please enter a numerical value. ')
                continue

            #DETERMINING TIP PERCENTAGE BASED ON QUALITY
            while True :
                if quality == 1 :
                    tip_percent = 0.15
                elif quality == 2 :
                    tip_percent = 0.20
                elif quality == 3 :
                    tip_percent = 0.25

                #CALCULATING PER PERSON TIP AMOUNT
                gross_tip = total * tip_percent
                perperson_tip = (total / guests) * tip_percent

                #PRINTING TIP PER PERSON AND GROSS TIP
                print('Per-person tip: ' + str(perperson_tip) + '\nGross tip: ' + str(gross_tip))
                exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you have all your while loops nested inside each other. There's no good reason for that.

```py
while True:
  try:
    total = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))
  except:
    print('Please enter a numerical value.')
    continue
  if total < 1:
    print('Please enter a value greater than 0.')
    continue
  break

while True:
  try:
    guests = int(input('How many guests? '))
  except:
    print('Please enter a numerical value. ')
    continue
  if guests < 1:
    print('Please enter a value greater than 0. ')
    continue
  break

# and so on
```

Comment: I would also refactor the loop + input checking into a function to avoid so much repetition.

Comment: 0x5453, it would require to pass converters and conditions as arguments. And conditions would be lambdas. They are difficult concepts for pythonic padawans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your accept conditions to break loops right inside `while`.
Then you may avoid explicit `break` and `continue` and strange endless `while True` altogether.

```
total = 0
while total < 1:
    try :
        total = float(input('Enter the total cost of the meal: '))
        if total < 1 :
          print('Please enter a value greater than 0. ')
    except :
        print('Please enter a numerical value. ')

guests = 0
while guests < 1:
    try :
        guests = int(input('How many guests? '))
        if guests < 1 :
            print('Please enter a value greater than 0. ')
    except :
        print('Please enter a numerical value. ')

quality = 0
while quality > 3 or quality < 1  :
    try :
        quality = int(input('How was the quality of your service? 1 - 3: '))
        if quality > 3 or quality < 1 :
            print('Please enter a value between 1 and 3. ')
    except :
        print('Please enter a numerical value. ')



if quality == 1 :
    tip_percent = 0.15
elif quality == 2 :
    tip_percent = 0.20
elif quality == 3 :
    tip_percent = 0.25

#CALCULATING PER PERSON TIP AMOUNT
gross_tip = total * tip_percent
perperson_tip = (total / guests) * tip_percent

#PRINTING TIP PER PERSON AND GROSS TIP
print('Per-person tip: ' + str(perperson_tip) + '\nGross tip: ' + str(gross_tip))
```